# How to fetch data from GraphQL API and pass it to other function file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, graphql

I'm trying to fetch data from graphql API and pass the result to an another file (Where i'll display these data before loop each item).

I tried retrieve data using 'client.query' but don't know how to pass the result to another file. I tried to use import, tried props and hooks but still not working (i don't know if i'm doing it right aswell).

My last plan was to use 'useQuery' to retrieve the query from the file 1 to pass it to file 2, but i'm getting "undefined" as a response.

Follow the code:

FILE 1 (Provider):

```
    import {
      ApolloClient,
      ApolloProvider,
      from,
      HttpLink,
      InMemoryCache,
      gql
    } from "@apollo/client";
    import { setContext } from "@apollo/client/link/context";
    import React, { FC } from "react";
    import * as Realm from "realm-web";
    require('dotenv').config();

    export const APP_ID = process.env.REACT_APP_REALM_APP_ID || "";
    const graphql_url = `https://realm.mongodb.com/api/client/v2.0/app/${APP_ID}/graphql`;

    const app = new Realm.App(APP_ID);

    async function getValidAccessToken() {
      const credentials = Realm.Credentials.anonymous();
      if (!app.currentUser) {
        await app.logIn(credentials);
      } else {
        await app.currentUser.refreshCustomData();
      }

      return app.currentUser?.accessToken;
    }

    const authLink = setContext(async (_, { headers }: any) => {
      const tokenId = await getValidAccessToken();
      return {
        headers: {
          ...headers,
          Authorization: tokenId ? `Bearer ${tokenId}` : "",
        },
      };
    });

    const httpLink = new HttpLink({
      uri: graphql_url,
    });

    const links = from([authLink, httpLink]);

    const client = new ApolloClient({
      link: links,
      cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    });

    export const APIProvider: FC = ({ children }) => {
      return <ApolloProvider client={client}>{children}</ApolloProvider>;
    };

    getValidAccessToken().then(() => {
      console.log(graphql_url, `Bearer ${app.currentUser?.accessToken}`);
    });

    //QUERY - 10 first transfers data
    export const Transfers_Data = gql`
      {
        transfers (sortBy:SCHEDULED_TRANSFER_DATE_DESC, limit: 10) {
          payer {
            name
          }
          recipient {
            name
          }
          scheduled_transfer_date
          status
          value
        }
      }
      `;
```

FILE 2 (index.tsx):

```
    import { Heading, styled } from "bumbag";
    import React, { FC } from "react";
    import { PageWrapper } from "../Base";
    import { Footer } from "../Base/Footer";
    import { Header } from "../Base/Header";
    import { useQuery } from "@apollo/client";
    import { Transfers_Data } from "../../API/Provider"

    const Page = styled.div`
      background-color: #fe724e;
      display: flex;
      flex: 1;
      flex-direction: column;
    `;

    const BalanceBar = styled.div`
      align-items: center;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      height: 100px;
      margin-top: 1em;
    `;

    const Balance = styled.div`
      align-items: center;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;

      span {
        color: #eaeaea;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: bold;
        letter-spacing: 0.05em;
        line-height: 1em;
        text-transform: uppercase;
      }

      h3 {
        font-size: 28px;
        line-height: 1.33em;
        margin: 0;
      }
    `;

    const Content = styled.div`
      background-color: #fff;
      border-top-left-radius: 12px;
      border-top-right-radius: 12px;
      box-shadow: 0 8px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
      flex: 1;
    `;

    const ContentWrapper = styled.div`
      height: 512px;
      overflow-y: auto;
      padding: 1.4em 1.25em;
    `;

    export const LastTransactionDiv = styled.div`
    margin-top:15px;
    height:auto;
    background-color:#fe724e;
    border-radius:20px;
    font-size:14px;
    color:white;
    padding:10px;
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 30px;
    grid-column-gap:10px;
    grid-row-gap:5px;
    `;

    export const Name = styled.p`
    margin:0;
    padding-top:10px;
    `;
    export const Value = styled.p`
    margin:0;
    padding-top:10px;
    font-weight:bold;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:flex-end;
    `;
    export const Date = styled.p`
    margin:0;
    padding-right:5px;
    font-size:12px;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:flex-end;
    align-content:flex-end;
    color:#D1D1D1;
    `;

    export const Status = styled.p`
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-size:12px;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:flex-start;
    align-content:flex-end;
    color:#D1D1D1;
    `;



    export const HomePage: FC = () => {
      const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(Transfers_Data);
      console.log(data + "ALOW");

      return (
        <PageWrapper>
          <Page>
            <Header>
              <BalanceBar>
                <Balance>
                  <span>Saldo</span>
                  <h3>R$ 4.215,50</h3>
                </Balance>
              </BalanceBar>
            </Header>
            <Content>
              <ContentWrapper>
                <Heading use="h4">Últimas transações</Heading>
                {data.transfers.map((tr: any) => (
                  <LastTransactionDiv key={tr._id}>
                    <Name>{tr.payer.name}</Name>
                    <Value>{tr.value}</Value>
                    <Status>{tr.status}</Status>
                    <Date>{tr.scheduled_transfer_date}</Date>
                  </LastTransactionDiv>
                ))}


              </ContentWrapper>
            </Content>
            <Footer />
          </Page>
        </PageWrapper>
      );
    };
```

Comment: undefined until loaded ... `if(loading) return <Loading />;` before main return .. if content extracted to other component then test it inside, (render loading) preserving rendering 'layout'/template

Answer (score 0):

try to read about React Context .

React context let you pass state across your whole application  , states that can hold data that fetched from your Api